# Is it possible to enable bash_completion for :! or :r ! in VIM?

Tags: vim, bash-completion

I can use :shell to enter current dir and run commands. bash_completion work fine.

But how get bash_completion working in *:! command* or *:r ! command* case?

**Note**. I am Emacs user and Emacs **M-!** command don't allow such things (also **M-x shell**, you need **M-x term** to get bash_completion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. What @Prince Goulash is referring to is a simple filename completion done by vim itself. If you know how to force bash to pipe completion variants somewhere you can create a completion function for custom command which may in turn call built-in  `:!`, but redefining completion for built-in commands is not possible.

I personally do not know how to do this with bash and know that trying to do so in zsh results in dirty hacks with redefining zsh built-in commands (like `compadd`), using pexpect (python), Expect (perl), expect (tcl), zsh/zpty or something similar to run shell in interactive mode and inventing zsh->vim IPC mechanism (in opposite direction it is much simpler) (I once started working on a similar module for zsh, but stopped as there were too much problems on this way).

Answer (score 1):

Have you got

```
set nocompatible
```

in your .vimrc? This automatically enables ex-mode completion for `:!`. To see the list of possible completions you could also use

```
set wildmenu
```

and investigate the `wildmode` options.